# VMware detects wrong drive as C:\

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vmware-esx

After installing SP2 to W2K3 straight after adding a second drive, my VM after restart is now detecting the 2 disks the wrong way around. I am getting "Operating System not found" and when I boot from a recovery disk it offers me the chance to log into "D:\Windows" - it should be C:!

What is the quickest way for me to get the VM detecting the drives in the correct order again so I can boot?

UPDATE:

Ultimately LukeR below is correct. I was able to do it from within "Edit Settings" on the individual hard drives rather than editing the vmx directly, but the SCSI order was the correct solution.

WHY did it happen? Because this was originally, months ago, a P2V server, and the P2V process had assigned C drive to SCSI 0:1 rather than 0:0. That was fine, right up to the point I added a second HDD, which ESX gave the ID 0:0. As soon as I rebooted, it decided 0:0 was the lowest and therefore primary partition, and tried to boot off that. All I had to do was switch the IDs around.

Comment: Yes, adding a second disk was the instigator of your problem.  It will always add on the lowest available scsi id, unless you specify otherwise.  For some reason (perhaps you originally had another disk that was removed due to resizing?) SCSI 0:0 was left unused.

Comment: One of my workmates says they have seen it before where a server that is put through P2V ends up with its HDD as 0:1 rather than 0:0. Something I will watch out for next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the .vmx file in the folder where your VM disk is held.

This holds configuration information for your Virtual Machine, you can edit it with a text editor. Shut down your VM first.

From one of my config files:

```
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "Ubuntu.vmdk"
```

This represents the system disk in this particular VM.

If you have multiple disks, you should be able to edit these entries to the correct order.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right and came to the same likely conclusion literally seconds before reading your post! However I've found I don't have permission to edit or copy the vmx file location directly - arranging it now.

Comment: Good stuff. Glad you got it sorted.